# XML web services error of authentication

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

Here is my code:

```
ServiceReference1.WS1CPortTypeClient S_Reference = new ServiceReference1.WS1CPortTypeClient("WS1CSoap12");

S_Reference.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "*****";
S_Reference.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "1!******";
S_Reference.GETDATA_XML(System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), "Organization_Names", "");
```

I get an error on this line of code:

```
S_Reference.GETDATA_XML(System.DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), "table_name", "");
```

The error is:

> Additional information: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="1C:Enterprise 8.3"'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your app.config or web.config file;

Can you try the following credentialtype;

If this does not solve your problem, please share you config file.

```
 <binding name="xxx">  
      <security mode="Transport">  
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />  
      </security>  
 </binding>
```